# How to get ALL 404 on images loading

Tags: javascript, html, image, cors, http-status-code-404

### The Problem:

I have a web page that loads a lot of images from external sources. Some of those images links can be broken and I have a script that get called via the `onerror` attribute that removes the image (and some related content like a title, some tags...) if it does not load.

That works OK in most cases, EXCEPT when the image server sends me a default image to replace the missing one. In this case, the `onerror` event does not fire and my page gets an ugly default image.

### What I want to do:

I want to be able to detect and get rid of those images.

### The questions:

1) Is there a way to detect the status code (404) of the image loading from the img tag? (From the researches I have made it does not seem to be possible but I'm still asking...).

2) If #1 is not possible, one solution seems to make the calls to load the images with something like `XMLHttpRequest` and the look at the response code. In that case:

- is there a more appropriate way that `XMLHttpRequest`?
- should I expect a lot of problems from CORS?

#### For reference, here is a draft solution based on `XMLHttpRequest`:

```
function imgLoad(url, onOk, onProblem) {
    'use strict';

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', url);
    request.responseType = 'blob';

    request.onload = function () {
        if (request.status === 200) {

            onOk(request.response);

        } else {

            onProblem();

        }
    };

    request.onerror = function () {
        // if the request fails

        onProblem();
    };

    request.send();
};


function onOk(response) {

    var body = document.querySelector('body');
    var myImage = new Image();
    myImage.crossOrigin = ""; // or "anonymous"

    var imageURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(response);

    myImage.src = imageURL;
    body.appendChild(myImage);
};

function onProblem(err) {
    // remove the image and the other related elements
};

function loadImage(url) {
    'use strict';

    imgLoad(url, onOk, onProblem);
};
```

#### Edit:

To answer to @O.o, the actual code is just something like this:

```
<img src="http://someimageurl.jpg" onerror="imgError(this);">
```

Just a simple img tag. The `imgError` fuction is the one that removes the elements related to the image if it doesn't load. But it does not work if a default image is returned, only if NO image is returned.

Comment: 404 error responses typically never have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header. That means you cannot access any properties of those responses from your frontend JavaScript code. So if an external server responds with a 404 that lacks the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header, then from your frontend code, you’re not gonna be able detect that it was a 404. All that you’ll be able to detect is that request the request failed. So if you want accurately detect 404s programatically, you can’t do it from frontend code. You should do it from backend code instead.

Comment: why don't you share the current code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the actual solution I implemented. In the same time I added lazy loading for the images. Here is the code, in case it helps anyone:

```
/**
* this function load the image using an XMLHttpRequest to be able to read the status code from javascript.
*/

function imgLoad(image, onOk, onError) {

    var url = image.dataset.src;

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', url);
    request.responseType = 'blob';

    request.onload = function () {
        if (request.status === 200) {

            onOk(request.response, image);
        } else {

            onError(image);
        }
    };

    request.onerror = function () {
        // if the request fails
        onError(image);
    };

    request.send();
};


/**
* This function is called if the image successfully loads. It just replace the "src" prop and the image is pulled from the cache from the browser.
*/

function onOk(response, image) {

    image.crossOrigin = ""; // or "anonymous"

    var imageURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(response);

    //image.src = imageURL;  // to use the blob response
    image.src = image.dataset.src;  // to use normal src and disk cache
    image.onerror = "";
    image.classList.remove("lazy");
};

/**
* small helper
*/
function loadImage(image) {

    imgLoad(image, onOk, imgError);
};


/**
* wrap up and lazy loading implementation
*/
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var lazyImages = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("img.lazy"));

    if ("IntersectionObserver" in window) {
      let lazyImageObserver = new IntersectionObserver(function(entries, observer) {
        entries.forEach(function(entry) {
          if (entry.isIntersecting) {
            let lazyImage = entry.target;

            loadImage(lazyImage);

            lazyImageObserver.unobserve(lazyImage);
          }
        });
      });

      lazyImages.forEach(function(lazyImage) {
        lazyImageObserver.observe(lazyImage);
      });
    } else {
      // fall back
      lazyImages.forEach(function(lazyImage) {
        loadImage(lazyImage);
      });
    }
  });
```

I did not include the "onError" function because it is very specific to my code and not super relevant here.